# What is best object to use to hold two Lists of data?

Tags: c#

I have 2 List of Double as follows,

```
private List<double> lineChartDataPayment;
private List<double> lineChartDataInterest;

public async Task SetLineChartData()
{
    lineChartDataPayment = await APICalls.SetLineChartData();
    lineChartDataInterest = await APICalls.SetInterestDataList();
}
```

I need an object that I can add these two lists to and sent to my chart so my chart can access the data as obj[0] to get the list of `Payment` and obj[1] to get the list of the `Interest`.

What is the best option?

Comment: What's wrong with private List<List<double>> combinedData;?

Comment: If you want to keep things simple, good and old `Array`. Since those lists will be bound by reference, there will be no problem adding those two lists in a array and query them by the index. If `Array` is not the way you intend, add more details on your restrictions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create own class - it will be much easy to read/understand and maintain your code.

```
public class Data
{
    public List<double> Payment { get; }
    public List<double> Interest { get; }

    public Data(List<double> payment, List<double> interest)
    {
        Payment = payment;
        Interest = interest;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it

```
public async Task<Data> SetLineChartDataAsync()
{
    paymentTask = APICalls.SetLineChartData();
    interestTask = APICalls.SetInterestDataList();
    await Task.WhenAll(new[] { paymentTask, interestTask });

    return new Data(paymentTask.Result, interestTask.Result);
}
```

And in your chart method understandable names will be much better then accessing them by hardcoded indexes

```
public void CreateChart(Data data)
{
    var payments = data.Payment;
    var interests = data.Interest;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to join the corresponding elements of the sequence. I certainly would not recommend doing some kind of every-other scheme; it will be hard to understand and even harder to maintain.

Instead, consider making an object representing the data for your chart; then use LINQ's `Zip` method to generate them. Using an anonymous type for brevity, it would look like:

```
lineChartDataPayment.Zip(lineChartDataInterest, (payment, interest) => new {
   Payment = payment,
   Interest = interest
});
```

Generally speaking, use an actual class rather than an anonymous type of course.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make a List of the Lists....something like:

```
List<double> listOne = new List<double>();
List<double> listTwo = new List<double>();

List<List<double>> result = new List<List<double>> {{listOne}, {listTwo}};
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need an object that I can add these two lists to and sent to my chart so my chart can access the data as `obj[0]` to get the list of `Payment` and `obj[1]` to get the list of the `Interest`.

In this case you can use a `List<List<double>>` to hold the data:

```
public async Task<List<List<double>> SetLineChartData()
{
    List<double> lineChartDataPayment = await APICalls.SetLineChartData();
    List<double> lineChartDataInterest = await APICalls.SetInterestDataList();
    return new List<List<double>> { lineChartDataPayment, lineChartDataInterest };
}
```

And you can use them like:

```
List<List<double>> data = SetLineChartData();
List<double> paymentList = data[0];
List<double> interestList = data[1];
```